# Django - use raw query and order by with parameter

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

```
    data_list = Data.objects.raw(
                    'SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY %(order_col_name)s',
                    {"order_col_name" : order_col_name})
```

I use this code but..Ordering doesn't work.
I think the raw function cann't pass the ordering column parameter.
Can anybody help?

Comment: You can not specify that with a parameter: the names of columns, tables, etc. should be mentioned in the query part, not the parameter part. This is one of the (many) reasons not to use a raw query, but the Django ORM.

Answer (score 2):

The names of columns, tables, etc. can not be passed as parameter: the parameters are used to pass values.

You can work with string interpolation, but this is quite unsafe, you thus should check before if `order_col_name` is a column name, since string interpolation is sensitive to SQL injection:

```
if 'order_col_name' in ('acceptable', 'column', 'names'):
    data_list = Data.objects.raw(
        f'SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY {order_col_name}'
    )
    # …
# …
```

But this is one of the (many) reasons why using the Django ORM is better than making raw queries. Usually raw queries should only be used if the query can not be turned into a Django ORM call (effectively).

Comment: Thanks! The code  example is simplified just for question, and I use this query for JOIN two tables without Foreign Key. I can't find solution to JOIN them without raw query.  And after join, I have to order by some column, so I used... So Is there no solution to ordering with parameter without string interpolation?

Comment: @Shale: can you ask a new question where you share the (relevant parts) of your models to JOIN.

Comment: I wrote new post! really thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536574/django-join-two-table-without-foreign-key