# Django - Join two Table without Foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, orm

I have two tables and want to join them..
but I can't do that without rawQueryset and raw SQL.

how can i join two models **without foreign key?** The columns for JOIN is not unique so it can't be PK and Foreign Key.

I want to get the SQL LIKE THIS

```sql
'SELECT * FROM genome AS A JOIN metadata AS B ON A.query_id = B.sample_id',
```

and this the models I used.

```py
class Genome(models.Model):
    query_id = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    matching_hashes = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```py
class Metadata(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=50) # Metagenome의 query id와 JOIN함
    sample_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Is a `query_id` unique per genomen? or is the `sample_id` unique per `Metadata`? In other words, in what direction is the relationship? a one-to-many, or a many-to-one?

Comment: Both query_id and sample_id column is NOT unique in each model. 
It's many to many.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

Firstly, construct a SQL query as desired

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM genome AS A JOIN metadata AS B ON A.query_id = B.sample_id"
```

User that SQL query in django DB connection like following:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()    
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

Or you can try to execute `raw()` as following

```
Genome.objects.raw(sql_query) # in some cases it may not work
```

Comment: Thanks but can't i get the Queryset result with ORM?

Comment: Yes we can do that but it may produce sub queries and increase execution time for huge data

Comment: @Shale I just updated the answer. you can try and let me know if it's not working. :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```py
sample_ids = Metadata.objects.values('sample_id')
Genome.objects.filter(query_id__in=sample_ids)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. but I need to JOIN two tables T_T ..